# Entity Framework & SQL Server CE - Underlying Provider Failed On Open

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am building an application for internal use by my organization. It connects to a SQL Server CE database stored on our data server. The program works fine on my machine, but whenever I try to deploy it to another user, I received the following error:

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Load(IQueryable source)
>   at RunBKSales.Edit_Menu.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> The underlying provider failed on Open.

The last line should be the InnerException. This is the code that throws the error:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.Combos.Load();
        dbContext.Products.Load();
        dbContext.Stores.Load();

        comboDataGrid.DataContext = dbContext.Combos.Local;
        productDataGrid.DataContext = dbContext.Products.ToList();
        storeDataGrid.DataContext = dbContext.Stores.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LOG_FILE, String.Format("{0} \t {1} {2} {3}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException.Message) + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

The "Data Source" of the connection string is an UNC path to the `.sdf` database file.

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" 
                 invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" 
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" 
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
                 invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
                 type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BKSalesModel" 
             connectionString="Data Source=\\FULL\UNC\PATH\db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Again, it works fines on my machine, so I am struggling with debugging it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Inner Exception of the "inner Exception" for the root cause error message!

You cannot use SQL Compact across a LAN, it is a single machine database (you can have several processes on the same machine use the same database located on a local disk, though)

For sharing data across a LAN you should use SQL Server Express